# How to prevent radio buttons from line breaking?

Tags: css

for a form I'm creating, I used css to display radio buttons as a toggle-switch.

However its not responsive at all. When viewing on mobile the "scale" 1-5 is broken up in pieces. My goal is to change the with of the scale responsively instead of it breaking up.

Somehow I can't seem to figure it out.

Here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/7byse1vk/

```
.toggle__label {
transition: all .25s ease;
display: inline-block;
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: #878787;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 0 30px;
min-width: 100px;
height: 48px;
line-height: 48px;
color: #a7a6ae;
text-align: center;
}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display: flex;` on the parent, remove the `min-width` from the labels (otherwise that will make them at least 160px wide each, too wide for mobile), and set them to `flex-grow: 1` so they fill the parent fluidly.

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.toggle {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.toggle__label {
  transition: all .25s ease;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #878787;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 30px;
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  color: #a7a6ae;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.toggle__input:checked + .toggle__label {
  background-color: #e5702a;
  color: white;
}

.toggle__label--left {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.toggle__label--middle {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  margin-left: -4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.toggle__label--right {
  margin-left: -4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.toggle__input {
  position: absolute;
  left: -99999px;
}

label {
  padding: 0.4em 2em 0.4em 0;
}

.toggle-btn-grp {
  margin: 3px 0;
}

.toggle-btn {
  text-align: centre;
  margin: 5px 2px;
  padding: 0.4em 3em;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 1px #CCC;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle-btn-grp.joint-toggle .toggle-btn {
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 0.4em 2em;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-right-color: white;
}

.toggle-btn-grp.joint-toggle .toggle-btn:first-child {
  margin-left: 2px;
  border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
}

.toggle-btn-grp.joint-toggle .toggle-btn:last-child {
  margin-right: 2px;
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
  border-right: solid 1px #CCC;
}

.toggle-btn:hover {
  border: solid 1px #a0d5dc !important;
  background: #f1fdfe;
}

.toggle-btn.success {
  background: lightgreen;
  border: solid 1px green !important;
}

.visuallyhidden {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
}

.visuallyhidden.focusable:active,
.visuallyhidden.focusable:focus {
  clip: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  position: static;
  width: auto;
}


/* CSS only version */

.toggle-btn-grp.cssonly * {
  width: 140px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.toggle-btn-grp.cssonly div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px 2px;
}

.toggle-btn-grp.cssonly div label {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.toggle-btn-grp.cssonly div input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
}

.toggle-btn-grp.cssonly div:hover label {
  border: solid 1px #a0d5dc !important;
  background: #f1fdfe;
}

.toggle-btn-grp.cssonly div input:checked + label {
  background: lightgreen;
  border: solid 1px green !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <input class="toggle__input" id="option-1" type="radio" name="input4" value="1">
  <label class="toggle__label toggle__label--left" for="option-1">1</label>

  <input checked="true" class="toggle__input" id="option-2" type="radio" name="input4" value="2">
  <label class="toggle__label toggle__label--middle" for="option-2">2</label>

  <input class="toggle__input" id="option-3" type="radio" name="input4" value="3">
  <label class="toggle__label toggle__label--middle" for="option-3">3</label>

  <input class="toggle__input" id="option-4" type="radio" name="input4" value="4">
  <label class="toggle__label toggle__label--middle" for="option-4">4</label>

  <input class="toggle__input" id="option-5" type="radio" name="input4" value="5">
  <label class="toggle__label toggle__label--right" for="option-5">5</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your CSS for the labels below and it'll work. This will scale them down properly. It's because at the moment they've got a minimum set width and are being stretch with the `padding` because they don't have `box-sizing: border-box;`.

```
.toggle__label {
  transition: all .25s ease;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #878787;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 30px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  color: #a7a6ae;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```